# How do I use ArrayList in C++?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, com

I have created a method who's return type is an ArrayList instead of List. And I have created a COM component. How do I access this ArrayList in my main application which is in C++?

ex:

```
 ArrayList fun1() 
 {
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

    al.Add("one");
    al.Add("two");

    return al;
 }
```

So how do I handle this return type in C++?

Comment: your question doesnt make any sense.

Comment: Almost exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036720/how-to-return-list-from-c-and-use-it-in-vc-through-com

Comment: And how does this differ from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032060/how-to-return-a-collection-of-strings-from-c-to-c-via-com-interop?

Answer (score 1):

Check [how-to-return-list-from-c-and-use-it-in-vc-through-com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036720/how-to-return-list-from-c-and-use-it-in-vc-through-com) or [how-to-return-a-collection-of-strings-from-c-to-c-via-com-interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032060/how-to-return-a-collection-of-strings-from-c-to-c-via-com-interop)