# How do I return a string array in c# and use it in unmanaged c++?

Tags: c#, c++, com

Can any one tell me how to return a String array from a method and use it in c#?

Suppose i have to return an array of {one,two, .....ten} and in c++ i have to display this 
array on console and perform some actions.

Comment: How is this significantly different from this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032060/how-to-return-a-collection-of-strings-from-c-to-c-via-com-interop?

Comment: He is asking it for the third time now... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036720/how-to-return-list-from-c-and-use-it-in-vc-through-com/1036781#1036781

Comment: But i am looking for the way to return strings and use them on main
() but in previous it is list here a string array

Answer (score 1):

See here for an example: http://haroonsaeed.wordpress.com/2006/08/11/interop-managed-c-and-c/

not done it my self but at a guess:

in C#  create assembly called csharpassembly.dll with the following class

```
using System;
namespace Csharpassembly  {
 public class CSharpClass {
   public static string[] GetStrings() { 
    return new string[] {"1", "2", "3"}));
   }
 }
}
```

But in your case. Have an assembly that creates the array in c# and havea mC++ program reference this assembly and call it:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#using <mscorlib.dll>
#using "csharpassembly.dll"

using namespace System;
using namespace Csharpassembly 

__gc class Test {
public:

    static void ProcessCShaperStrings()     {
        array^ stringArray = CSharpClass::GetStrings();
        Console::WriteLine(stringArray [0]); ...
        // etc

    } 
};
int wmain(void) { 
    Test:: ProcessCShaperStrings();    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's about C# and managed C++ and the OP asks about C# and unmanaged C++.

Comment: That blog post seems to be a very good answer in my view. Is it possible for you to detail in your answer a little of what is explained in the blog post? That way your answer will still be helpful if haroon saeed's blog ever becomes unavailable.

Comment: @sharptooth the OP doesn't really indicate whether he is referring to managed or unmanaged C++

Comment: There is always going to be interop. Why not just take the above  example and populate a unmanaged datum in ProcessCShaperStrings(). Then the main() above could renamed to return this datum which you consume in an unmanaged consumer.