# How to return a list of strings in C#

Tags: c#, visual-c++, com

Can anybody tell me How to store and return List of Strings.

I am asked this Because i have written a function which returns Collection of strings and I want to prepare a COM for that one and need to consume that COM(to get the returned list ) in VC++ where I can extend some functionality using that list of strings. I hope this would be clear.

Comment: Please provide more information - store permanently oder just "build a list/return that list"? "Return" like as the result of a method?

Comment: It is really unclear what you mean; either this is trivially simple, or deceptively deep, depending on your intent...

Comment: more input please, 
what do you want to achieve?
pseudocode could help

Comment: It is not clear what *exactly* is the problem you are facing. I suggest you post the code snippet and let the code speak.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[List<string>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) or string[] are the best options.

Here is a sample method that returns list of strings :

```
public static List<string> GetCities()
{
  List<string> cities = new List<string>();
  cities.Add("Istanbul");
  cities.Add("Athens");
  cities.Add("Sofia");
  return cities;
}
```

Comment: I did like the same. But i prepared a COM for this and want to get 
That return values in c++ where i have to use this returned values.But i am geting error that GetCities(as example) is not a method of corresponding interface. Guide me to resolve this one

Answer (score 4):

In C# you can simply return `List<string>`, but you may want to return `IEnumerable<string>` instead as it allows for lazy evaluation.

Comment: (the lazy evaluation only really being useful if backed by a lazy source)

Comment: @Marc: Certainly, but if you return List<string> you don't have the option even with a lazy source.

Comment: @Marc - or if you want the option in the future of switching to a lazy source :)

Answer (score 3):

You can store a fixed list of strings as an array:

```
string[] myStrings = {"Hello", "World"};
```

Or a dynamic list as a `List<string>`:

```
List<string> myStrings = new List<string>();
myStrings.Add("Hello");
myStrings.Add("World");
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to represent a list of strings in .NET, List<string> being the slickest. However, you can't return this to COM because:

1. COM doesn't understand .NET Generics
2. FxCop will tell you that it's bad practice to return an internal implementation of something (List) rather than an abstract interface (IList / IEnumerable).

Unless you want to get into really scary Variant SafeArray objects (not recommended), you need to create a 'collection' object so that your COM client can enumerate the strings.

Something like this (not compiled - this is just an example to get you started):

```
[COMVisible(true)]
public class CollectionOfStrings
{
  IEnumerator<string> m_enum;
  int m_count;

  public CollectionOfStrings(IEnumerable<string> list)
  { 
    m_enum = list.GetEnumerator();
    m_count = list.Count;
  }

  public int HowMany() { return m_count; }

  public bool MoveNext() { return m_enum.MoveNext(); }

  public string GetCurrent() { return m_enum.Current; }
}
```

(See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352856.aspx for more help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352856.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday you asked how to do this via COM interop! Why the step backward?

[How to return a collection of strings from C# to C++ via COM interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032060/how-to-return-a-collection-of-strings-from-c-to-c-via-com-interop)

Comment: I get a downvote for reminding the user to check the question they asked yesterday?! Great.

Comment: Still i am trying to do this one through "COM".But i am knowing my way is corrct or no

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IList<string> GetStrings()
{
  foreach( var item in GetStringItems())
  yield return item;
}
```