# How to pass 2 string lists to c++ from c# through COM?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, com

I need to pass string lists to unmanaged c++ how can I do this ?

I have used `IDictionary` as method return type and send through com but it doesn't work. How to achieve this?

What I have written in `C#` is as follows -

```
IDictionary<string,string> postNames()
{
  IDictionary<string,string> post=Dictionary<string,string>();
  post.Add("Raj");
  post.Add("Mahesh");
  post.Add("john steek");

  return post;  
}
```

Then I have created a `dll` for that class contains this method.

Now how can i access these values in unmanaged c++....

I am worried about two things

1) About the return type to carry these values in c++

2) Is it possible to use like this way ..

Any help in this regard?

Comment: Not enough info, I think.

Is the COM object/interface already defined or are you creating a new method for this?

Comment: What kind of list is that on the C++ side? 
MFC CList? STL List? or just plain old null-terminated array?

Comment: Why IDictionary? A dictionary contains pair of key-value element, yet you only have keys, no values. You only add strings, it seems more appropriate to return a string[] or System.Array.

Answer (score 1):

A quick, dirty method is write a C++/CLI wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

It's essentially the same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032060/how-to-return-a-collection-of-strings-from-c-to-c-via-com-interop). You can implement perfect [Earwicker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032060/how-to-return-a-collection-of-strings-from-c-to-c-via-com-interop/1032356#1032356) here - declare a set of interfaces and accessor classes that wrap the Dictionary and expose them to COM.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way is to pass a string[] and use it in the unmanaged side as an [SAFEARRAY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221482.aspx)(BSTR) type. You can also pass a string[] and consume it in COM as a LPStr[] by using the MarshalAs (this is the sample on MSDN):

```
void FunctionCall([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPARRAY, 
   ArraySubType= UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeParamIndex=1)] 
   String [,] ar, int size );
```

See [Default Marshaling for Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6.aspx) for more details.