# Passing .NET types around with COM DLL's

Tags: c#, dll, com

I currently have a registered DLL made in C# for COM. A method that returns a list of strings `List<string>` is not being recognised. I assume it's because of the List type. Is it not possible to pass .Net types around like this? Must I stick to basic array's and custom structures / classes as returns?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return a collection of strings from C# to C++ via COM interop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032060/how-to-return-a-collection-of-strings-from-c-sharp-to-c-via-com-interop)

Answer (score 0):

Only Standard COM types can be passed by COM objects between COM objects, no matter what language you write them in.

You can write marshalling code to deal with your own datatypes, but that is a very large undertaking.

You will need to find a way of either passing around COM objects themselves or Variants, Variant Arrays or Strings.